# Foreach in SQL Server using joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a small issue with a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005.

`RepInfoID(primary), Date, RepID` are the columns in `RepInfo`

```
 1. 25660, 02/03/2012, 100
 2. 25661, 02/03/2012, 100
 3. 25662, 02/03/2012, 101
```

and

`RepCID(primary), RepInfoID, Amount` are the columns in `RepCollection`

```
 1. 4343, 25660, 200(money)
 2. 4344, 25661, 600
```

Desired results is:

```
100(RepID) , 02/03/2012, 800(money)
```

There can be more than row with the same date.

When a date is selected, foreach `RepID` on the selected date, I want the sum of `Amount` on that particular day. I hope I am clear.

Thank you for your help..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PracticewithAmount]
(@Date datetime)
AS
BEGIN
Select * 
    from RepInfo 
left outer join RepCollection on RepInfo.RepInfoID = RepCollection.RepInfoID    
where RepInfo.Date = @Date 
      and distinct(RepID)
END
```

Comment: You should provide sample data...

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. While I like reverse engineering word problems, it's not appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but here's what I think you're saying:

```
SELECT
   --i.RepInfoID(primary), 
   i.Date, 
   i.RepID,
   --c.RepCID(primary),
   --c.RepInfoID,
   sum(c.Amount) as Amount
FROM
   RepInfo i

   LEFT JOIN RepCollection c
   ON i.RepInfoID  = c.RepInfoID    
WHERE
   i.Date = @Date
GROUP BY
   i.Date,
   i.RepID
```

Comment: Thank you!! I got the logic too!